# Adding and using a variable in dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

I'm trying to take an existing Mantis Bug Tracker docker image, and extend it in a way that depending on the environment variable, I move the mantis website to the corresponding folder. This is what I came up with:

```
FROM vimagick/mantisbt:latest
MAINTAINER kev <me@janjko.hr>

RUN mkdir /var/www/tempMove && \
 mv /var/www/html/* /var/www/tempMove/ && \
 mkdir /var/www/html/${MANTIS_FOLDER:-mantis} && \
 mv /var/www/tempMove/* /var/www/html/${MANTIS_FOLDER:-mantis}
```

I use ${variable:-word} syntax, and "mantis" is default. When I use this image, the website always winds up in the mantis folder, meaning, it doesn't pick up my string from docker-compose:

```
environment:
  - MANTIS_FOLDER=example
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Replace `${MANTIS_FOLDER:-mantis}` with `$MANTIS_FOLDER:-mantis`

Answer (score 0):

According to [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args) documentation you need to use `ARGS`: build arguments, which are environment variables accessible only during the build process.

> Note: If your service specifies a build option, variables defined in
>   environment are not automatically visible during the build. Use the
>   args sub-option of build to define build-time environment variables.

`Dockerfile` should be modified to:

```
FROM vimagick/mantisbt:latest
MAINTAINER kev <me@janjko.hr>

ARG MANTIS_FOLDER

RUN mkdir /var/www/tempMove && \
 mv /var/www/html/* /var/www/tempMove/ && \
 mkdir /var/www/html/${MANTIS_FOLDER:-mantis} && \
 mv /var/www/tempMove/* /var/www/html/${MANTIS_FOLDER:-mantis}
```

`docker-compose.yaml` should be modified as well:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        MANTIS_FOLDER: example
```